# Text field on UIAlertController triggers disabled button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIAlertController` with a `UITextField` and a submit button. The code looks like this:

```
let saveDialogue = UIAlertController(title: "Save Level",
    message: "",
    preferredStyle: .Alert)

let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default,
    handler: { (action) in
        let textfield = saveDialogue.textFields![0] as UITextField
        // do something with the textfield
    }
)
saveAction.enabled = false
saveDialogue.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "My Level"
    textField.text = filename
    // conditionally enable the button 
    textField.addTarget(self, action: "textChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

}
```

While the button cannot be tapped, hitting the return key on the keyboard triggers the default action (`saveAction`).

Is there a way around this? I also tried to validate the textfield value in the handler, but the view will be dismissed. Can it be retained?

Comment: You want to call button saveAction on hitting return key? Can you elaborate what exact problem you are facing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to ignore the return key input, set textField's delegate and return false in `textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method.

Like bellow:

```
saveDialogue.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "My Level"
    textField.text = "hello"
    // conditionally enable the button
    textField.addTarget(self, action: "textChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

    // Add this line
    textField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: I was writing the exact same answer but you were quicker :) One more precision, though: I think that instead of `return false`, he wants the text field to validate only if the submit button is enabled (and I guess it's getting enabled/disabled based on the content of the text field...).

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the same problem little bit differently.

```
//where alert is variable in class 
    override func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                            shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                            replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if range.location >= 1 { return true } // if we have one or more characters

        guard let isTextFieldEmpty = textField.text?.isEmpty else { return true }

        if !isTextFieldEmpty {
            alert?.actions.first?.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            alert?.actions.first?.isEnabled = true
        }
        return true
    }
```